# How can I compute the formula of simple linear regression in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have this data:

```
x <- c(1,3,5,8,9,0)
y <- c(5,8,9,7,4,3)
xy <- data.frame(X = x, Y = y)
```

I draw the simple linear regression line with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
MyRegression <- ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y))
MyRegression + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

Also I want to have automatically the type of the equation *y=a+bx*. I know how to compute *a* and *b* (by using [this formula](http://data:image/png;base64,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)), but I 'm wondering if I can do it automatically by using a simple command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate a linear model, use the R-fucntion `lm`.

```
mod <- lm(Y~X,data=xy)
```

Now you want to calculate the fitted line. This is possible via

```
lineData <- data.frame(x=xy$X,y=mod$coefficients[1]+mod$coefficients[2]*xy$X)
```

You can add the line by using `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line(data=lineData,mapping = aes(x=x,y=y),col="red",size=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you believe that `geom_smooth(method='lm')` is not the correct way to draw the regression line?